# Authorization for window.location.href call in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, window.location

I am working on a Web application. I have two seperate projects for UI and APIs. The apis require authentication for accessing. I wrote a common code to pass the token for each api call.

```
    App.config(function ($httpProvider) {
$httpProvider.interceptors.push('authInterceptorService');    
});
```

This is my authInterceptorService factory code.

```
    var localStorageLocation = ngAuthSettings.localStorageLocation;

        var authInterceptorServiceFactory = {};

        var _request = function (config) {

            config.headers = config.headers || {};

            var authData = localStorageService.get(localStorageLocation);
            if (authData) {
                    config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + authData.token;
            }
            return config;
        }
    authInterceptorServiceFactory.request = _request;
```

Now I have an API to download a pdf file. I am using 'window.location.href = uri'. But I am getting unauthorised exception. Now I want to know if there is a way to pass my token in the request. And is there any other way to access my file download url other than using window.location(I prefer using window.location but at this point I am desperate it to work in some way or other).

Comment: I didn't mean to say I am getting an exception. I meant I can't access the api and I am getting ''Authorization has been denied for this request." as response.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up. Can you share the request and corresponding response from the _Network_ panel of your browser? It would help provide some context as to the cause of the unauthorized request.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way could be passing the token within the url: /pdfuri?token=token

The way we achieved that in my last project is calling the pdf API (with ajax) that returns a temporary url where you can download your pdf.

Comment: passing the token from the url still results in unauthorized response. And yes I can return an url which doesn't require a token and set window.location to this, but I want to know if there is any option other than exposing an api which is not secure.

Comment: Of course if you send the token in the query string you should also change the backend, cause you won't find any header. The second option is not less safe: you would send an url that expires in something like 10 mins and that consists in a hash. I used this method in a homebanking, so I guess it's safe enough...